# Sort files with grep

Tags: bash, grep, sorting, pipe

I have a few hundreds of output files, of which some contain error messages. Lets say I want to automatically put all files containing the string "ERROR_1" in a "subfolder_1", and the rest in a second "subfolder_2". This should be possible by piping grep somehow. What would be a useful syntax?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295710/sorting-with-unix-tools-and-multiple-columns) might help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for a in *;do grep -q ERROR_1 "$a" && mv "$a" subfolder_1 || mv "$a" subfolder_2;done
```

This should work.

Answer (score 4):

This script will move the files into the subfolders. Modify  the wildcard `*` as required (e.g. `*.log`) - this code will search all files in the current directory

```
for f in *
do
    grep -f ERROR_1 "$f"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
       mv "$f" subfolder_1
    else
       mv "$f" subfolder_2
    fi
done
```